# Extra-factual meaning

Tags: meaning

I have searched in the net with no avail. I need to know the meaning of

> extra-factual

as well as a synonym for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factual means "true, based on facts" and the "extra-" prefix means "outside, not including"

So we have terms like "extra-terrestrial" (alien, from outside of the Earth). "Extra-marital" (sex or relationships outside of marriage)

So Extra-factual means "outside of the facts" or "not true".  In particular, it means propaganda. Lies and deception used in conflicts to deceive the enemy. Extra-factual, and the acronym "EFI" (Extra factual information) is a euphemism for propaganda